# Add seconds to date for time feedback

Tags: php, datetime

Hey everyone im trying to display relative date and time messages to the user, so for example if the file was updated less then 5 seconds ago the message the user will see is: 'Updated Just Now' however it doesnt seem to be working.

Here is the code that I am using

```
function relativeTime($date) {
    $timeNow = date('M d Y H:s');

     if ($date == $timeNow || $date == date('M d Y H:s', + 500)) {
         echo "Updated Just Now";

     } else {
         echo "not now";
     }
}
```

This is where I am displaying it and passing it the argument:

```
<?php relativeTime(dateUTCtoLocal("M d Y H:s", $arrSchool["updated"]));?>
```

I eventually will have a few if's in there for minute and hours, am I going about this the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're looking for if the time it was posted is less than five seconds ago. Easy, but you MUST use timestamps. Formatted times are no good.

```
relativeTime($arrSchool['updated']); // if it's a numeric timestamp
relativeTime(strtotime($arrSchool['updated'])); // if it's a datetime string

function relativeTime($timestamp) {
    if( $timestamp > time()-5) {
        echo "Updated Just Now";
    }
    else {
        echo "not now";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the input date string into a Unix timestamp using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and calculate the difference between the input date and current time, and display the message if the difference is less than 5 minutes (5 * 60 = 300 seconds):

```
function relativeTime($date) {
    $timeNow = date('M d Y H:s');
    $diff = strtotime($timeNow) - strtotime($date);

     if ($diff < (5*60)) {
         echo "Updated Just Now";
     } else {
         echo "not now";
     }
}
```